# Compare two text files, extract matching rows of file2 plus additional rows

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, python, pattern-matching

have been mocking around with this too long and tried grep, join, awk but I cant get the parameters right. I need to get the command right.

I have got two text files.

> cat file1

```
@ABC:11:ABC:1:1111:1111:1111
@ABC:22:ABC:1:1111:4444:4444
```

> cat file2

```
@ABC:11:ABC:1:1111:1111:1111 1:N:0:TCCCGCGC+AGGCGGGG
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
+
#FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
@ABC:11:ABC:1:1111:2222:2222 1:N:0:TCCCGCGC+AGGCGGGG
AGGCGGGGAGGCGGGGAGGCGGGGAGGCGGGGAGGCGGGGAGGCGGGGAGGCGGGGAGGCGGGG
+
#FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
@ABC:22:ABC:1:1111:3333:3333 1:N:0:TCCCGCGC+AGGCGGGG
AGGCGGGGAGGCGGGGAGGCGGGGAGGCGGGGAGGCGGGGAGGCGGGGAGGCGGGGAGGCGGGG
+
#FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
@ABC:22:ABC:1:1111:4444:4444 1:N:0:TCCCGCGC+AGGCGGGG
TTTTTTTTTTTTTGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
+
#FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

I would like to do the two things:

**output 1)** Based on file1, extract all rows that contain the strings plus two additional string.

**output 2)** Based on file1, extract all rows that **do not** contain the strings plus two additional rows - but it should only try to match lines that start with @..

Example output 1):

> cat output1

```
@ABC:11:ABC:1:1111:1111:1111 1:N:0:TCCCGCGC+AGGCGGGG
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
+
#FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
@ABC:22:ABC:1:1111:4444:4444 1:N:0:TCCCGCGC+AGGCGGGG
TTTTTTTTTTTTTGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
+
#FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

Example output 2)

> cat output2

```
@ABC:11:ABC:1:1111:2222:2222 1:N:0:TCCCGCGC+AGGCGGGG
AGGCGGGGAGGCGGGGAGGCGGGGAGGCGGGGAGGCGGGGAGGCGGGGAGGCGGGGAGGCGGGG
+
#FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
@ABC:22:ABC:1:1111:3333:3333 1:N:0:TCCCGCGC+AGGCGGGG
AGGCGGGGAGGCGGGGAGGCGGGGAGGCGGGGAGGCGGGGAGGCGGGGAGGCGGGGAGGCGGGG
+
#FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

(no perl please  )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are showing and asking for is to grep a given set of reads in a fastq file. I strongly recommend not to reinvent the wheel and use existing tools like [seqkit grep](https://bioinf.shenwei.me/seqkit/usage/#grep) for it.

Nevertheless here the "bash-only" variant:

4 consecutive lines belong to one read. So we can put them all in one line, delimited by tabs, grep for the ids and transform back the tabs to new lines.

```
$ cat file2.fq|paste - - - -|grep -f file1.txt|tr "\t" "\n"
```

Or for your second output we just use the invert parameter for `grep`

```
$ cat file2.fq|paste - - - -|grep -v -f file1.txt|tr "\t" "\n
```

Comment: Thanks, thats great. The paste - - - - did the trick. Very nice. Did not know seqkit, but it looks very useful.